# Почта, отправленная через mailgun помещается в спам лист

Tags: email, рассылка

Имеется приложение, которое отправляет форму восстановления пароля через сервис mailgun. В теле письма имеется информация и ссылка на веб сайт. Почтовые сервисы gmail, mail.ru помещают отправленные письма в спам лист. Есть ли способ избежать этого?

Answer (score 2):

При отправке писем с облачных почтовых сервисов есть несколько пунктов, которые нужно соблюсти:

### Добавить в Mailgun домен, с которого отсылаются письма

Mailgun предоставляет временный домен/адрес вида `sandbox275a1376f9c547b4a5d2a3b511234567.mailgun.org` для отправки писем. Но если письма вы отсылаете с вашего личного домена - его необходимо зарегистрировать в Mailgun.

Например, если письма уходят с `no-reply@foobar.com` - значит в Mailgun нужно добавить домен `foobar.com`, которым вы владеете. Сделать это можно [в личном кабинете Mailgun, следуя инструкции](https://mailgun.com/app/domains/new).

### Добавить DKIM и SPF записи

Когда почтовый сервис получает откуда-то письмо - он узнает, с какого сервера оно пришло, и с какого домена. Например, наше письмо, отправленное через Mailgun, прилетит в почтовый сервис с серверов Mailgun (связанных с mailgun.org), и с адреса `no-reply@foobar.com`.

Почтовый сервис выясняет две вещи:

1. Действительно ли письмо пришло от владельца домена `foobar.com`? Его ведь мог отправить кто-угодно с подобного адреса..
2. Письмо пришло со сторонних серверов Mailgun, не связанных напрямую с доменом. Позволяет ли владелец домена `foobar.com` отправлять письма через сервера Mailgun?

Для этого почтовый сервис обращается к DNS-записям домена, и по их наличию - понимает, что письмо действительно было прислано владельцем домена и с одобренных им серверов. В противном случае - такое письмо почтовый сервис посчитает мошенническим, и отправит в спам.

В Mailgun также есть инструкции по добавлению DKIM и SPF записей. Добавлять их нужно в DNS-настройках вашего домена. Либо там, где вы его покупали, либо на сторонних NS-серверах, например на [pdd.yandex.ru](http://pdd.yandex.ru/).

После добавления сервера в Mailgun - в личном кабинете зайдите на страницу этого домена (ссылка такого вида: https://mailgun.com/app/domains/foobar.com), и следуйте инструкциям Mailgun.

Answer (score 1):

А другой сервер не пробовали? Или отправлять со своего сайта?
Есть ряд способов, которые помогают повысить доверие к вашим письма (т. е. снизить вероятность расценивая их как спам). Очень хороший сборник рекомендаций есть у google - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=ru

Вот некоторые моменты из него:

- Для осуществления массовых рассылок используйте постоянный IP-адрес.
- Для IP-адресов, с которых отправляются сообщения, должны существовать действительные обратные записи DNS, указывающие на ваш домен.
- Используйте во всех письмах массовой рассылки один и тот же
  адрес в поле "От:".
- Подписывайте сообщения ключом DKIM. В Gmail принимаются ключи длиной не менее 1024 бит.
- Опубликуйте записи SPF.
- Опубликуйте политику DMARC.

Используя собственный cервер вам будет удобнее контролировать выполнение этих требований.